# Using vertical align to align the text to the top of the div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to use vertical-align: top to align the text to the top of the div, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#outer {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
}
img {
display: inline-block;
}
#message {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'>
<img src = "https://www.iscattered.com/uploads/7195c3cfadac848470ae8f00c0b1e2aa4ae.jpg">
<div id = 'message'> 
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
message message message
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `vertical-align` on the text element rather than the container. The `vertical-align` directive aligns an element within a context, it doesn't affect the element's parents.

**Working Live Demo:**

```css
#outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
#message {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <img src="https://www.iscattered.com/uploads/7195c3cfadac848470ae8f00c0b1e2aa4ae.jpg">
  <div id='message'>
    message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message message
    message message message message
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since text-align is suppose to be put on the parent, this whole vertical align thing just threw me off. I thought it was suppose to work the same way.

Comment: @frosty Yep, CSS is a fickle beast. MDN page for vertical align: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align